Copy range text including soft hyphens from Word to Excel or Access while avoiding clipboard
I'm trying to copy text inside a cell of a narrow Word table including soft hyphens produced by MS Word's AutoHyphenation feature to Excel or Access.
It works, when the soft hyphens are already available in the table cell.
Run the attached code in MSWord the first time after uncommenting the commented code lines:
Option Explicit


Sub CopyWithHyphens()
  Dim oExc As Object, excWB As Object, excSheet As Object
  Dim myStart As Long, myEnd As Long, CopyRange As Range

  Const xlPasteValues = -4163
  
' when uncommenting the below lines, on my system, the softhyphens aren't available in the table cell until the Sub has finished,
' obviously auto-hyphenation cannot proceed during VBA processing?????
  
'    Dim TestTable As Table
'
''prepare table
'    With ActiveDocument
'      .AutoHyphenation = True
'      If .Tables.Count > 0 Then .Tables(.Tables.Count).Delete
'    End With
'    Set TestTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= _
'                                                 1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
'                                                 wdAutoFitFixed)
'    With TestTable
'      .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
'      .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
'      .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
'      .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
'      .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
'      .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
'      .AllowAutoFit = False
'      With .Columns(1)
'        .SetWidth CentimetersToPoints(1.999), wdAdjustNone
'      End With
'      With .Cell(1, 1).Range
'        .Text = "This is a long text for demonstration of Autohypenation in a table cell"
'      End With
'    End With

  'select string to copy from the Table,
  'remove Cell-Text-End Marker (1 character)
  With ActiveDocument
'    .Paragraphs(1).Hyphenation = True
    myStart = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Start
    myEnd = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1
    Set CopyRange = .Range(myStart, myEnd)
  End With

  CopyRange.Copy      'copy the selelcted range, now including also the soft hyphens within the text

  'open Excel
  Set oExc = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  If Not oExc Is Nothing Then
    Set excWB = oExc.Workbooks.Add
    Set excSheet = excWB.worksheets(1)
    oExc.Visible = True

    excSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues   'paste the text of the reduced CopyRange to Excel
  End If
  Set oExc = Nothing
  '..
End Sub

Run the code again after commenting the previously uncommented code lines.
Running the code uncommented the first time transfers the string without soft hyphens, running it re-commented the second time transfers also the soft hyphens, which is the expected behaviour.
To run the procedure multiple times is unstable when using the clipboard to transfer the data. Is there a method to transfer the text with the soft hyphens included?
I tried to store the data in an object by using range.xml, but the soft hyphens are not included; the behaviour is similar to using stringValue = range.text.

I thought you might be able to use ConvertAutoHyphens, then Undo the action. But that action does not seem to Undo. I mention it only in case I missed something obvious!

using ConvertAutoHyphens put me on the right track. At least in Break-mode after applying ConvertAutoHyphens, the variable CopyRange now includes softhyphens (Chr$(31)), MSWord is using for conditional hyphens.
Copyrange can be transferred to Excel or Access via a Variant variable.
Appreciate your help!
